# Software for WordPress Theme and Plugin Development?

Tags: theme-development, plugin-development

What software do you use for your WordPress related needs?

Please state your OS.

On windows XP I use:

- filezilla (FTP)
- notepad++ (for reading of PHP / CSS files)
- firebug  (a firefox extension to allow me to play with a website elements)

Other things which I don't use regularly, but would like to use more
 - xaamp (local version of WP)
 - github/SVN (a version control system for my files)

What about you?

Comment: GREAT question for a community wiki!

Comment: Debugging is essential when developing WordPress Themes and Plugins. Also I know that this is a really old question. But hope this will help someone. I have written an article for an easy way to debug WordPress plugins. Find the below link. https://digitecz.com/web-development/how-to-debug-wordpress-using-browsers-javascript-console/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

OS **Windows** 7 x64

### Using

- [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) excellent non-free IDE, a lot of focus on speed and productivity
- [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) debugger, a lot of useful functions to dump, trace stack, profile
- [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) secure file transfer, folders sync, remote editing, backup
- [Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/) WAMP stack, portable, up to date components
- [Internet Explorer Collection](http://utilu.com/IECollection/) easy way to have multiple IE for testing
- [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) local files backup
- [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) off-site backup storage (in context of WP)
- [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) MySQL client
- [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups) interface sketching
- [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) command line interface
- [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) those plugins won't run themselves

  - [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) do I need to explain? :)
  - [HTML Validator](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/) integrates with source view
  - [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) performance
  - [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) performance
  - [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) various nifties
  - [SEO Doctor](http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/browser-addons/seo-doctor) solid no-fluff on-page SEO check
  - [View Source Chart](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/view-source-chart/) color-coded and foldable page source view
- WordPress plugins

  - [BackupBuddy](http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) backup and migration
  - [WordPress Console](http://github.com/sant0sk1/wordpress-console) cool, handy, but glitches at times
  - [Codestyling Localization](http://www.code-styling.de/english/development/wordpress-plugin-codestyling-localization-en) must have for translations
  - [list hooks](http://www.rarst.net/script/debug-wordpress-hooks/) (shameless plug) several functions for hooks debug
  - [Theme-Check](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/) runs battery of tests on theme for official repository theme requirements
  - [Core Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) very useful to debug file system access, network access and wp cron
  - [Codex Generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codex-generator/) (shameless plug) functions research and filling up Codex

### Version control

- [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)

  - [official WP repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/)
  - [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/)
- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)

  - [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)

  - [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/)

### Considering

- [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) plenty development extensions already, Firefox is damn slow

### Deprecated

- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) almost never use it since picked up NetBeans
- [PHPXref](http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/) easier to navigate code inside NetBeans
- [WP Tuner](http://blogs.icta.net/plugins/wptuner/) great performance profiling, unfortunately not maintained and broke for WP3
- [MoWeS](http://www.chsoftware.net/en/mowes/mowesportable/mowes.htm) became too much trouble to struggle with component updates and stability issues (Apache started to crash all the time)
- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) moved on to PhpStorm
- [eAccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/) - modern version don't provide object cache, somewhat unstable (occasional crashes)
- [webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind) - no need anymore, PhpStorm can now parse and display profiler logs
- [CSE HTML Validator](http://www.htmlvalidator.com/) just never get to use it on top of everything else
- [MySQL Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) replaced with HeidiSQL

Comment: i tried NetBeans after your post. Just opened a utf-8 encoded file that include utf-8 chars and it fails. file was contained "şŞ Üü Çç İı Öö" etc chars. Btw notepad++ have no problem with that file

Comment: @Ünsal Korkmaz I hadn't looked deep into how NetBeans works with UTF-8, can only say I had no issues so far with Cyrillic characters.

Comment: How is Uniform Server compared to Bitnami WAMP stack?

Comment: Hadn't used the latter, still using Uniform though.

Answer (score 13):

I use both Mac and PC. Here are my respective toolboxes:

I have a personal subversion repository on my server (Mediatemple dv)

For both platforms:

- A local [PHPXref](http://phpxref.com) running out of a constantly updated svn checkout of trunk
- [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)
- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

For PC (Vista Home Premium):

- [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) for an SSH CLI
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the [NppFtp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/) plugin as my text editor
- [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) for SVN
- [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) (when I really have to. I usually just use SVN instead)
- [Spoon.net's browser sandbox](http://www.spoon.net/browsers/) for cross-browser testing

For Mac (OSX):

- [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/) for text editor, SVN, and SSH CLI
- [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) for FTP (again, I usually just use SVN) Parallels w/ Windows XP for cross-browser testing
- Terminal for SVN (sometimes)

Comment: I'm on a Mac, is XAMPP better than MAMP?

Comment: I have no idea, since I've never used MAMP. All I can say is that XAMPP works for me. What's important is that you use a LAMP stack.

Answer (score 11):

xdebug (the best way for write great source and see the hints of WordPress, maybe deprecated functions) and also the possibilities of WordPress, like constant WP-DEBUG

```
/** Debugging WP */
define('WP_DEBUG', true); //enable the reporting of notices during development - E_ALL
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true); //use the globally configured setting for display_errors and not force errors to be displayed
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true); //error logging to wp-content/debug.log
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true); //loads the development (non-minified) versions of all    scripts and CSS and disables compression and concatenation,
//define('E_DEPRECATED', true); //E_ALL &amp; ~E_DEPRECATED &amp; ~E_STRICT
```

more about my toolbox in [this post](http://wpengineer.com/2011/our-wordpress-developer-toolbox/) , but current I use PhpStorm as IDE, also GitHub as Repository.

Inside WordPress I use the plugin [Debug Objects](https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects) for a lot of jobs in the debugging content.

Answer (score 8):

I used a PC until last year and now Mac and PC so here are mine:

### For both Mac & Windows:

- [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) - FTP Client
- [Firefox Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) - jQuery Debugging
- [Navicat for MySQL](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql) - Commercial MySQL client
- [Unfuddle.com](https://unfuddle.com/) - SVN Repository and Task Management for client projects

### For Mac (OS X):

- [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)+[Zend Debugger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-zend-debugger.html) - Debugging IDE (Nothing better on the MAC)
- [VirtualHostX](https://retina.studio/virtualhostx/) - Manages Apache Virtual Hosts Locally (I *LOVE* this)
- [Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/) FTP Client w/synchronization
- Terminal for SVN (sometimes)
- [Fraise](https://github.com/jfmoy/Fraise/) - Lightweight Text Editor (Fork of [Smultron](https://www.peterborgapps.com/smultron/))
- [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) - Text Editor w/great visual regex search & replace
- [Safari 5](https://www.apple.com/safari/) + [Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) - For inspecting HTML+CSS + Safari Enhancements
- [HTTP Scoop](https://www.tuffcode.com/) - Reasonable HTTP debugger\
- [Acorn](https://flyingmeat.com/acorn/) - Image Editor
- [Skitch](https://evernote.com/products/skitch) - Image Annotator and Uploader
- [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/) - Mockups and Wireframes
- [Cinch](https://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/) - Easy Full Screens (OS X should do this but it doesn't)
- [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/) - Automated core file backup and file synchronizer across computers
- [Paparazzi!](https://derailer.org/paparazzi/) - Batchable screen-shot tool
- [TotalFinder](https://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) - Tabs Finder

### For Windows (Vista Business):

- [PhpED](http://www.nusphere.com/products/) - Debugging IDE (Nothing better on Windows, 'cept maybe [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)+[XDEBUG](https://xdebug.org/))
- [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) - Great open-source MySQL client
- [Notepad2](https://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) - Great lightweight and usable Notepad alternative
- [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) - SVN Client
- [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) - Unbeatable command-line scripting
- [IE Developer Toolbar](https://web.archive.org/web/20111023051305/http://www.microsoft.com:80/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en) - For inspecting HTML+CSS on Internet Explorer
- [Fiddler 2](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) - Unbeatable HTTP debugger
- [FinePrint](https://fineprint.com/fp/) - 2, 4 and 8 up printing (Oh how I miss it on OS X!)

That's about it.

### UPDATE:

I deleted [Flow (FTP client)](https://fivedetails.com/flow/) from my list and replaced it with [**Transmit** (FTP Client)](https://panic.com/transmit/) which is a much better tool. Thanks for the great recommendation *@John P Bloch!*

Comment: Mike, there is a great Firefox Add On called [Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/) that may reduce your need for Paparazzi!

Answer (score 7):

For plug-in development, I use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr) for PHP development.

Answer (score 7):

I run on Ubuntu (always the latest version)

I like to keep things as simple as possible

My tools of choice:

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/Download/Releases) for writing code

Filezilla for FTP

Gimp for slicing and dicing designs prepared by my design team (who run Photoshop/Illustrator on Windows)

Dropbox for sharing files between developers/designers

Googletalk and skype for chat/voice comms between developers

A white board for planning

And testing in Chrome, Firefox on Linux and for Windows: Chrome, Firefox, Safari and [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) (for IE) which I fire up on an ancient Windows XP PC I call my 'deadbox'

Answer (score 7):

#### Recently made the move to Mac from Windows

**Currently Using: Mac OS 10.6.7**

- [PHP Storm 3](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)  with the [CSS-X Plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?webide&id=5348) (Integrates with Firebug and saves and versions live CSS edits.
- Xdebug
- Capistrano
- [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) and <del>[ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/mac) (Mounts remote folders on startup) for SFTP</del>
- <del>[Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) for basic editing when I don't want to open PHP Storm</del>
- I do all code editing in PHP Storm now
- <del>[LittleSnapper](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/) for screen shots and annotations</del>
- Terminal and nano for working on my live server
- [MAMP Pro](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/index.html) for local dev environment
- [Photoshop CS5](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=photoshop) for graphix
- [Omnigraffe](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) for wireframes
- [VmWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html) for running Windows 7 inside my Mac

**WebApps**

- [FreshBooks](http://www.freshbooks.com/) for invoicing and expense tracking
- [BidSketch](http://www.bidsketch.com/) for creating proposals
- [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/) for processing credit cards
- [EchoSign](http://www.echosign.com/) for processing electronic signatures
- [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) for Email, Calendar and docs

**Deprecated (for me) Windows Software**

- NetBeans IDE
- Notepad ++
- Core FTP
- Putty and PuttyGen
- WinSCP

**Windows Software using in Virtual Machine**

- [IPMI View](http://www.servethehome.com/supermicro-ipmiview-review-remote-server-monitoring-management-ipmi-20-kvm-over-ip/) kvm-over-IP for controlling my server

Comment: Putty Deprecated?

Comment: Deprecated for me because I don't use Windows anymore.

Comment: ah you should have said Windows:Everything. lol

Answer (score 6):

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04:

- Vim (text editing)
- Firebug (CSS debugging)
- Gimp (image manipulation)
- Inkscape (vector art)
- Git (version control)
- Filezilla (FTP)
- Apache (local Wordpress install)

Answer (score 6):

OSX:

- Coda & Espresso for PHP/CSS
- Netbeans IDE for CSS, XHTML, PHP editing etc.
- Firebug for debugging in FireFox
- Transmit for FTP
- Balsamic for wireframes
- Git for version control
- Photoshop for Comps
- Vmware Fusion for development machines:

  Anyone can download "for free" any LAMP, Python, Django etc prebuilt VM from http://turnkeylinux.org

Comment: +1 for the link to TurnKey Hub - very, very interesting, especially for site migration.

Answer (score 5):

On my PC:

1. XAMPP for local dev
2. Winscp for SFTP/FTP
3. Git for version control
4. Sublime for editing text

On my Mac

1. Transmit for SFTP/FTP
2. MAMP for local Dev
3. Textmate for coding
4. Terminal for working with Git
5. Gitx for the odd visual view of Git repos
6. Snippets for storing my code snippets

Answer (score 5):

I'm developing on ubuntu (currently running 10.04).

For wordpress development, I use:

1. geany (quick editing script)
2. eclipse (when on full development)
3. RapidSVN (or eclipse's SVN plugin)
4. FileZilla
5. PHPMiniAdmin and PHPMyAdmin
6. FireBug (for javascript and CSS editing)
7. Password management with LastPass.com

My strategy when developing plugin hosted on wordpress, I develop that plugin on eclipse's workspace and create symlink from trunks to `wp-content/plugins`. That way, I can manage my plugins better.

Answer (score 4):

**Operating Systems:**

- Windows XP (primary)
- Windows Vista 64 (when i'm not on the laptop)

**Tools:**

- Notepad++ with the Zen Coding plugin (for everything code)
- FileZilla (for FTP when i need it)
- Uniform Server (PHP/MySQL/Apache + xdebug which i installed)
- Firefox Nightlies + Firefox Stable (trunk + stable)
- *Firefox Ext*:

  - Firebug
  - Web Developer
  - Stylish 
    _
- TortoiseSVN (for SVN goodness)
- Fireworks CS3 (image manipulation)

I think i've covered the important (can't live without) ones.. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice thread. I use many of the same tools as above and on windows and linux flavors. Maybe the ones that I use specifically and not mentioned:

- total commander for comparing directories and files and ftp-ing: http://www.ghisler.com/ (basically free but shareware, I 'bought' it some years ago)
- RTC for versioning and todo lists: http://jazz.net/projects/rational-team-concert/
  (its free for up to 10 users)
- dreamcoder for mysql (free sql management): http://www.sqldeveloper.net/database-tools/mysql/overview.html
- Xara for all graphics: http://www.xara.com/eu/ (yes I bought it and keep upgrading since the first versions it is now € 279 but it is really worth it)
- Irfanview ( http://www.irfanview.com) for quick image copy/pasting/operations and batch processing
- Wireshark ( http://www.wireshark.org/) (free) - to test if e.g. a RPC call is ok
- sometimes Artweaver ( http://www.artweaver.de/) (free) for tablet drawings
- i manage my zillions of passwords for all these sites with roboform (http://www.roboform.com/) ( paid also for mobile), lastpass ( https://lastpass.com/) free and keepass ( http://keepass.info/), still havent found the most best solution

Comment: I am huge fan of Total Commander, but I won't recommend to use it for FTP. That part had always been unstable for me and support for secure protocols is only available via rough plugins, because developer can't legally develop such features in his country.

Comment: Well... lets take this to http://www.ghisler.ch/board/index.php :)

Answer (score 4):

Not many have listed the things they use on the customer end of things so I thought I'd share my list:

- [Zendesk](http://zendesk.com) for customer support and forums
- [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com) for source control and bug tracking
- [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com) for reliable sending and tracking of e-mails to customers
- [Maxmind](http://maximind.com) for fraud checking and automatic phone confirmation on developer edition
- [oDesk](http://www.odesk.com) for when I get behind fixing bugs
- [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com) for e-mail marketing to customers
- [RamShyam](http://ramshyam.com/) - First level of tech support

I also use [this Yahoo pipe I made](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=60a76855bb956f8c86f66117bc808c6d) to monitor WordPress security issues and releases and I like to use [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) for quick testing of code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP I use:

- FileZilla (FTP)
- Dreamweaver (PHP/CSS/JS)
- Firebug (a lot of debugging)
- IETester (To make sure things don't explode in IE6)
- WAMP (To run a local testing server)
- Tortoise SVN (To track local changes and sync with the WP Plug-in Repository)
- Flyspray (an online bug tracker I run on a hosted server)

Answer (score 1):

I use Windows 7 for development and the following tools:

- Netbeans IDE for CSS, XHTML, PHP editing etc.
- Notepad++ for some quick editing...
- XAMPP for local development environment.
- Firebug for debugging.
- Google Page Speed and YSlow for site speed optimization.
- FileZilla for FTP.
- SilkSVN for Source control.. Required for Wordpress Plugins
- Putty for ssh
- etc....

Answer (score 1):

I just use Netbeans php ide,heidiSql,FileZilla,Firebug and Web Developer.
Question,is there a similar tool like PHPXref?Some other widnows app?

Comment: I think commonly mentioned alternative is [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/). Only used PHPXref myself and mostly switched to navigating in NetBeans since I started to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Well most everything is covered here:)

So I will list stuff that isn't, most this is for Windows.

[Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) its grep for windows and it's free.
[NexusFont](http://xiles.net/downloads/#NexusFont)  free font manager for windows, simple has no really good advanced tagging:(
[Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) link sleuth broken link checker, crawler and site maps, amazingly fast.
[iBBDemo](http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662) iphone and ipad tesing
[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Documentation) Virtual boxes!
[Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) For translating code/stuff and making .mo/.po files.
[CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/)  make vids for clients.
[Vector Magic](http://vectormagic.com)  the magical world of vectors, not free but well worth it
[Collorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/firefox/) for firefox, can't work without.
[Ruby backup](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup)  for linux/osx
[Whenever Gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)   ruby cron tool

Answer (score 1):

I use [Fakemail](http://www.lastcraft.com/fakemail.php) to test diverse mailing functionality of the software.

Answer (score 0):

on OSX:

1. Aptana for code and svn.
2. MAMP for the Apache server.
3. YummyFTP for ftp.
4. Safari.
5. VMWare Fusion and Windows XP for
   testing.

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked to keep things pretty simple.

- Notepad++
- FileZilla
- Google Chrome (love "Inspect")

I really should learn about GIT/SVN etc, but haven't needed it so far.

Answer (score 0):

Most of my tools have already been listed, so repeating them won't add to this discussion any, but some ff extensions not mentioned before that I find useful are:

- Codeburner for firebug (Reference tool, by SitePoint)
- Colorzilla (eyedropper tool)
- MeasureIt (ruler/measurment tool)

I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

My main editor is Dreamweaver CS5, Dreamweaver's had a bum rap in many developer's eyes I think but it's improved a lot in the last few versions. For WordPress dev then the latest CS5 release brings direct support for working with WordPress as well as greatly improved PHP auto-completion so it's a pretty nice coding environment, as well as offering some pretty handy tools for those with a more visual development leaning.

I'm working on OSX but it's pretty much the same on Win or Mac really. Dreamweaver does also offer Subversion integration but personally I prefer to use either [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/) or [Versions](http://versionsapp.com) on Mac to deal with SVN.

Answer (score 0):

I try to keep things simple and separated.

I run a Ubuntu server with Apache, MySQL, PHP to use exclusively for testing and hosting work-in-progress for review by others.

Tools on my Mac (development machine):

- [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda) for editing files
- [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit) for FTP - I can mount the server's www directory right on my desktop!
- Terminal for SSH to the server
  ...and [Google](http://www.google.com) for help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned BBEdit yet.

I made the switch from Windows to OS X a year or so ago and the one thing that I couldn't find was an editor that just felt right. I finally settled on BBEdit and have not looked back. There are so many layers of functionality within it, which I am enjoying discovering.

Answer (score 0):

W7 / x64:

- NetBeans for PHP, HTML, CSS (& LESS, though the plug-in does not function perfectly).
- XAMPP for environment.
- TortoiseGIT for some projects (with GitHub)
- TortoiseSVN for other projects (with Beanstalk)
- Browsers, all.
- Photoshop.
- Excel (CSV -> SQL).
- WP Plugin [Theme-Check](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/)

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OSX 10.6.8

- [Aptana v1.5](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/311-aptana-20-or-older-versions) - this old version has some amazing php capabilities and an awesome local/remote syncing tool with diff previews. 
  Sadly even v3 can't match v1.5 for php features and I've yet to find a more modern IDE that can browse a complex object hierarchy so intuitively. Not easy to configure for remote xdebug, but can be done.
- [Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/) - FTP with local/remote sync capability
- gitx - basic git gui for OSX
- CSSEdit - For really big stylesheets or non IDE work. Now part of Espresso
- Kod - Lightweight text editor
- Ubuntu server in VMWare Fusion. I prefer this to MAMP as I can create different VMs to match the production environment of different hosts.