# Is there any tool to find lines of codes responsible to generate front-end HTML elements?

Tags: theme-development, php, templates, html

Dreamweaver CS5 is very useful to design or modify a Wordpress theme. It inspects CSS elements in Live view (after seting up a test server), but its unable to trace original wordpress code responsible for generating front-end HTML. So, I'm looking for a smart dev tool which could trace internal PHP code responsible for generating selected front-end HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any decent IDE for PHP comes with search capabilities. It is usually rather easy to find code responsible if it uses specific ids and/or class names.

Personally I use NetBeans for PHP, also see [Software for WordPress Theme and Plugin Development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324/software-for-wordpress-theme-and-plugin-development) question. A tons of good tools mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

Any IDE with a built in debugger would be useful to you.  I use http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ .  It's very simple to setup with a debugger.

There are IDEs out there that requires you to add a debugger as a module and you spend most of your time making the module work instead of debugging your own code. That's why I suggest something as simple as PHPStorm.