# Where do I start from

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I'm student web developer and I'd like to know the things I should know before venturing into WordPress. Where do I start?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Glad your taking the jump into wordpress, wordpress is an amazing platform for developers and non-developers alike, if you have knowledge of PHP, HTML, CSS (and jQuery in some instances) you will enjoy working with wordpress.

A great place to start understanding wordpress would of-course be the wordpress website itself.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page

I hope this helps, for more specific tutorials and tips / tricks i find myself scouring google every-time i need something.

Comment: Thank you so much Xavier. I'll  start working on my PHP and jquery skills immediately.

Answer (score 6):

[WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) is **official documentation wiki** for the project. It is far from perfect in advanced corners, but basics are covered well.

Since you will need to spend a lot of time in WordPress source, it is best to have it installed and running on your local computer. Any **decent Apache-MySQL-PHP stack** will do. **PHP debugger** and good **PHP-aware IDE** will be more than beneficial.

You can see what typical tools of WordPress developers are in this question - [Software for WordPress Theme and Plugin Development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324/software-for-wordpress-theme-and-plugin-development)

Answer (score 0):

You can use many of the available tutorials on internet. 
Use this https://developer.wordpress.org/ and you can be an expert. If you feel hard to follow there are hundrerds of tutorials available. I would suggest the following tutorials.

- https://www.taniarascia.com/tutorials/#wordpress
- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/theme-development/
- https://code.tutsplus.com/series/developing-your-first-wordpress-theme--wp-338

Please make use of it if you are still helpless