# Where is it better to start learning how to develop for Wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development

I have already read this question and answer to it ( [Where do I start from](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13793/where-do-i-start-from) ).

So I have slightly different question. If I basicaly have no knowledge of how the WordPress code is structured and I have some ideas for plugin I would like to write should I start at the same place where author of the answer sugested in the post linked above or there is some other path?

Thanks to all who will contribute to this question.

P.S. I have more than 3.5 years of experience with PHP and other web technologies.

Comment: what is the end game? Theme developer? Plugin developer? Wordpress contributor?

Comment: As I mentioned in question "I have some ideas for plugin I would like to write"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book [Digging into WordPress](http://digwp.com/) is a good start. I bought this myself. I found it to be full of useful resources.

If you want plugin development then [Professional WordPress Plugin Development](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-WordPress-Plugin-Development-Williams/dp/0470916222/) is a great book. Another book I bought and I used it to develop my first plugin.

Other places to keep visit are [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) and the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress)

Comment: +1 for Professional WordPress Plugin Development, I wish the book was written when I started to get more serious with internals. If PHP is not an issue than it should jump start person on WordPress nicely.

Comment: So I guess this named books are better start then just plain reading of `Wordpress Codex`?

Comment: Yes I would say its a best start. That doesnt mean you should pay any attention to the CODEX. Its a valuable source of information but because it is user submitted it can be missing some large bits. With a book it generally gives you all that you need in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've got 3.5 years of experience with PHP, a good place to start are the WordPress core files in wp-includes. Getting a hang of those files will give you an idea of where all the functions come from.

Of course it may seem like a daunting task to look through hundreds (if not thousands) of functions, but i believe the core developers did a great job on commenting on the basic functionality and purpose of each function. Perhaps checking out the latest version of WordPress through svn  would be your best bet to stay up-to-date with latest bug fixes and improvements.

Heres a link to the WordPress trunk https://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk.

Heres another link to the WordPress codex on Plugin Development [WordPress Codex: Plugin Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [the very best place!!](http://codex.wordpress.org/) It is called the Codex and it does help very often. Full of useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the core files. Best would be to include the [krumo class](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) into Twenty Ten theme and then simply write `krumo::includes();` at the beginning of Twenty Tens functions.php file. This will show you which file gets loaded when and help you learning the way wp works pretty fast and easily.