# Wordpress Beginer to Guru

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is it better to start learning how to develop for Wordpress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16731/where-is-it-better-to-start-learning-how-to-develop-for-wordpress)

Hi I have recently started learning WordPress threw these video series [WP101](http://wp.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/wp101-training/) on wptuts+ and after that I took the default theme and arras theme and started customizing theme a bit to get a feel of how to work with WordPress.

My goal is to learn as much about the platform as possible in the next 3 months that includes theme development and even plugin development.I have one year experience in working with html/css/javascript and 4 months in PHP&MySql.

What is a good book or resource on theme development?What about plugin development?
I prety much managed to familiarize myself with every component on the admin panel is that enough to move forward to theme development?If not can someone post some resource to familiarize myself better with the panel.

I should mention I am trying to add WordPress to my skill bag because I am trying to get a job as a web developer and this days it seems that a knowledge of a CMS is require everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this forum is the best place to post these kinds of questions - ie ones that have [subjective answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), but I'll take the bate anyhoo as I'm just starting myself.

I've read a few by Sitepoint. Honestly I've begun to get a bit tired of their style, as they've clearly struck on a formula for writing texts, but its clear, up-beat and easy to absorb. Take a stab at [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/wpant1/) and [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/wordpress1/).

Comment: Not to be persnickety, but WPSE is **not** a forum.

Comment: I take your point - I was being sloppy in my use of language. What should we call WPSE though? It has most of the atributes of a forum even if its spirit is different.

Comment: The stackexchange model is that of a "question & answer site". The essential difference to a forum isn't necessarily the spirit, but the format of one question and one one or ideally several on-topic answers. Not having to wade through "I have a similar problem" or "I dunno, but have you tried this alternative?"-type posts is the distinguishing factor that makes this site so valuable. Don't get me wrong, WPSE needs more users willing to write quality answers - I never meant to discourage you (or others, for that matter) to do so. Just wanted to point out that "forum" is the wrong title.