# Any Cool Wordpress Theme Editor?

Tags: theme-development, themes, editor

I am looking for wordpress theme editor, Is there any Cool Wordpress Theme Editors available for free??If you have worked with share your experiences here ..
And also the links to download them with why is that editor is the best one or better one ??

Answer (score 3):

Technically WordPress theme is combination of PHP, HTML, CSS and JS (or some subset of these). There isn't such thing as WP theme editor, but any editor or IDE that is good for such combination will do. It depends on your personal preferences, operating system and if you want free or paid solution.

See this questions for many good software suggestions - [Software for WordPress Theme and Plugin Development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324/software-for-wordpress-theme-and-plugin-development)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Kate when I'm in Linux, and Notepad++ when I'm unfortunate enough to be using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a built in editor that let's you edit themes from your wordpress admin. To access it, go to the dashboard (in the wordpress admin), then go to `appearance>editor`.

Comment: It sucks in appearance , known as Tinymice..I feel trouble working with it ..

Comment: TinyMCE - not Tiny mice!

Comment: Tinymice has nothing to do with this editor: this is not the editor that you use to create posts. This is **another** built in editor that let's you edit themes. Give it a try, and if you don't like it, you can customize it with a plugin: (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=codepress), or you can use another editor.