# Super WordPress debugging toolkit and triage procedures?

Tags: debug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software for WordPress Theme and Plugin Development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324/software-for-wordpress-theme-and-plugin-development)

What do you use or carry with you in your "toolbelt" when approaching an existing WordPress site that you've got to extend or maintain? Is there a good Windows debugger? Are there essential addons you install, things you FTP right away?

Comment: This is a very subjective question that doesn't have one "right" answer. Marking as community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I use [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) for php debugging, couldn't live without it.

Answer (score 0):

xDebug and Webgrind is very usefull for an great work; but maybe you will read more as example in this [post](http://wpengineer.com/2011/our-wordpress-developer-toolbox/).

Answer (score 0):

[Core Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) plugin is essential. Mostly for cron tasks overview, but at times other functions (like HTTP logging) are also uniquely useful.