# Top Contributors Plugin with Custom Post Type

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I am using the plugin [Top Contributors](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/top-contributors/). That's very helpful for all blogs. But the problem with this plugin is: it is not integrated with custom post types.

How could I extend the plugin to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin hasn't been updated in almost two years, so you should consider finding a new one.

That said, in this cases you have to open<sup>1</sup> the plugin files and search for some string related to your issue, e.g., `post_type`.

You'll find that in the file [`functions.inc.php`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/top-contributors/tags/1.4.1/functions.inc.php), it has two occurrences of:

```
AND a.post_type = 'post'
```

Change that to:

```
AND ( a.post_type = 'post' OR a.post_type = 'YOUR_CPT_SLUG' )
```

Not sure if that's the only thing that needs to be changed, but now you should be able to further inspect it and locate other parts that need modification.

<sup>1: [Software for WordPress Theme and Plugin Development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/324/12615)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution is [Top Authors](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/top-authors/)
Its support CPT now. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-support-2?replies=3#post-3967338